# Tridion 2011 SP1 UGC

Tags: tridion

After going through the UGC install guide I'm having trouble actually adding comments.  I've got the datasource for the CMS pointing to the webservice:-

```
<DataSource>
<Key>1</Key>
<Match>^(ugc:|oe:|tcm:)+</Match>
<Url>http://project.ugc.service/odata.svc</Url>
<TimeOut>100000</TimeOut>
<Threshold>0</Threshold>
<RatingMinimum>-1</RatingMinimum>
<RatingMaximum>5</RatingMaximum>
<OAuthEnabled>false</OAuthEnabled>
<Locale>en-us</Locale>
<ClientId></ClientId>
<ClientSecret></ClientSecret>
<EventSystemClientId></EventSystemClientId>
<EventSystemClientSecret></EventSystemClientSecret>
<AccessTokenUrl></AccessTokenUrl>
</DataSource>
```

I've got the ODATA service returning data so that appears to be working.

I've got the Ambient Data Http module specified in the CD config.

```
<add type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" name="AmbientFrameworkModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

But when I try to add a comment using the CMS I just get the message in the CMS GUI "Saving comment failed".  Where should this log to as I can't see any logs that are relevant?

Any pointers much appreciated.

Thanks

John

Comment: Did you also configure the UGC bundle in cd_storage_conf? Logging info should be available in cd_core.log of the website and/or the odata webservice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nuno.  As far as I know the UGC bundle is configured correctly.  In my storage bindings I have the ugc_dao_bundle.xml specified - am I correct in thinking that this isn't a pointer to an actual file though?  In the logs I'm getting Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'UGC_COMMENTS'.  The SQLJDBC4 jar is in the lib folder and the database connection to the UGCDB is in the storage_conf.

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Comment: Now half solved.  The issue was that I was publishing a specific publication that had it's own entry in cd_storage_conf.  This specific entry was being picked up as my pages were being published correctly, however, the UGC item typeMappings in the specific publication weren't being picked up so UGC entries were going to the default storage which is the broker DB ,hence, the Invalid object name error. The UGC item typeMappings only appear to be picked up if I move them out of the specific publication node in the config and into the main ItemTypes node.  Anybody know why this would be the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I was publishing a specific publication that had it's own entry in cd_storage_conf. This specific entry was being picked up as my pages were being published correctly, however, the UGC item typeMappings in the specific publication weren't being picked up so UGC entries were going to the default storage which is the broker DB ,hence, the Invalid object name error.

The UGC item typeMappings only appear to be picked up if I move them out of the specific publication node in the config and into the main ItemTypes node.  Not sure why this would be the case though.

Answer (score 3):

The error "Saving comment failed" usually indicates that the end point of the UGC Content Delivery Web service is not correctly configured or not accesible from the CM server.

Make sure that after changing the `..\Tridion\web\WebUI\Models\UGC\Configuration\DataSources.xml` file, you restart IIS so this updated configuration is read. Clearing your browser cache and reloading the CME also can't hurt.

The ugc_dao_bundle.xml file is a real file, but it is located inside the ugc_storage.jar, so as long as that is in your lib folder, you should be fine.